# adding printer in remote machine is not working: invalid printer name

Tags: powershell, remoting, network-printers

I have gone through many blogs for finding solution for this issue, but never find a solution.

```
$CompName = "test.domain.com"
$Printer = "\\122.21.10.11\PRINTER-NAME-1"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $CompName -Scriptblock {
  Param($p)
  (New-Object -Com Wscript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection($p)
} -ArgumentList $Printer
```

I have even tried `PSRemoting` and tried to execute the `ps1` file from remote machine. the same script is working in local and not working remote.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "testserver.testdomain.com" -Authentication Credssp -Credential Get-Credential
```

Error:

> Exception calling "AddWindowsPrinterConnection" with "1" argument(s): "The printer name is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070709)"

**Updates:**

Working without CredSSP:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotemac.mydomain.com -ScriptBlock {
  Get-ChildItem C:\Users\myusername\Desktop
}
```

Working with CredSSP:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotemac.mydomain.com -ScriptBlock {
  Get-ChildItem \\sharedmac\sharef
} -Authentication Credssp -Credential mydomain\myusername
```

Script is working, but not showing network printers:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotemac.mydomain.com -ScriptBlock {
  (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).EnumPrinterConnections()
} -Authentication Credssp -Credential mydomain\myusername
```

Script gives error: Invalid Printer name

```
$Printer = "\\172.26.30.13\SDB1-FLOOR1-B2" # I have tried this input in single, double, with and without escape character
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotemac.mydomain.com -ScriptBlock {
  Param($p)
  (New-Object -Com WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("$p")
} -ArgumentList $Printer -Authentication Credssp -Credential mydomain\myusername
```

I'm totally stuck.

I heard we can use Group Policy, is there anyway we can automate this using group policy?

Comment: "remotemac"? Are you trying to run this on a Mac? Did you configure CredSSP on server and client as described in the article I linked to? What does your network topology actually look like?

Comment: not mac OS  machine, its just a dummy name. Yes, CredSSP configured properly. it works fine for other scripts, i have verified it. both machines are in the same domain. ports are opened. nothing is blocking. should we have to implement remoting with the Printer Server (where printers are available. )$Printer = "\\172.26.30.13\SDB1-FLOOR1-B2" this server: 172.26.30.13

Comment: Any others answers? how about using group policy?

Comment: google://group+policy+add+printer yields a metric ton of results. Please do some legwork yourself.